# Create database design with requirement

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I has a small database structure with an **Account** and **Person**. I want apply the following requirement:

**Account** have one **Person**

**Person** do not have necessarily one **Account** (can be null)

When I delete an **Account** I don't necessarily delete **Person**

When I delete a **Person** I want delete **Account**

How to do that ? (one to one relationship ? on delete cascade ?)

This is good ?

[image]

### Some clarification after getting some answers:

Thank for your answers.
I try to explain more the contextual meaning of **Account** and **Person**.

A **Person** is a contact with personal profile (Physical person, Customer, Company).

An **Account** is specified by an username, password, email. It's really an account for sign in on a app.

Therefore a **Person** can be exist without a account. A **Person** can only have a maximum of 1 **Account**. In a other direction **Account** have necessarily a **Person**.

Consequently when we remove an **Account** the **Person** is not also remove. But When I remove **Person** this associated **Account** no longer needed.

PS: I use PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would state it like this:

- Each **Person** may be **the holder of** one or more **Accounts**.
- Each **Account** must be **held by** one and only one **Person**.

Given that, let's address a few of the questions and statements posed:

> Person do not have necessarily one Account (can be null)

The **Account** would not be null.  Instead, there just wouldn't be a row in **Account** for that **Person** as they hold no accounts.  Now if you write an outer join of **Person** to **Account** then yes, for those persons with no accounts the columns from the account, which is the null supplying side, will be null.

> When I delete an Account I don't necessarily delete Person
>
> When I delete a Person I want delete Account
>
> How to do that ? (one to one relationship ? on delete cascade ?)

You are right on with a one to many relationship from **Person** to **Account**, not a one to one relationship.  You are also correct you want deletes of a person to **cascade** to ensure that when a person is deleted the associated accounts are deleted with it.

In your drawing you have, under the **Account** table:

> Constraints - person_id is unique

and under the **Person** table:

> Constraints - person_id is DELETE_CASCADE, UPDATE_CASCADE

Both of these are not technically correct. Regarding **person_id** on the **Account** table, since the relationship is one person to many accounts, the same person_id will be in the account table for each account that person holds.  It would look like this:

```
account_id     person_id
----------     ---------
1              1
2              1
3              1
```

The **account_id** is unique, not the **person_id**.

Regarding **person_id** as a constraint under the **Person** table, actually the foreign key constraint is placed on the **Account** table, referencing the **Person** table.  That constraint is then declared to cascade on delete and update actions.  The constraint on the **person_id** in the **Person** table would be a **primary key** constraint.

Here is a revised drawing of the relationships using [Oracle SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html):

[image]

The oracle tool places an X over the crows foot on the many side to show that the delete rule is CASCADE.  It also shows the keys, which show the foreign key constraint with **person_id** on the **Account** table, and the primary key constraint with **person_id** on the **Person** table.

Answer (score 1):

An Account belongsTo a Person. A person can exist without an account.

If a Person hasOne Account, then Account's primary key should also be a foreign key to People.

```
create table people (
  person_id int primary key,
  meta1 text, 
  meta2 text
);

create table accounts (
  person_id int primary key references people(person_id) on delete cascade,
  meta1 text
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good if you want a Person to have 0 or many Accounts.

If a Person can only have a maximum of 1 Account, then I'd put the account details in the Person table.